# How to test API Controller with async functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm trying to Unit test my API Controllers using MSTest. I'm following the tutorial mentioned here: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2

The tutorial above sadly doesn't cover what tweaks to make to make it work for async functions in the controller.

In the code below, the test runs successfully if I run it on a non-async controller action. But when I test it on async function it gives me an error.

```
public async Task GetService_ShouldReturnCorrectServiceId()
{
    //Arrange
    var context = new TestContext();
    context.Services.Add(new Service { Service_ID = 1, Service_Name = "WEBAPPS"});

    //Act
    var controller = new ServicesController(context);
    var result = await controller.GetServiceId("WEBAPPS") as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Service>;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Content.Service_ID);
    }
```

Test fails giving this error:

> the provider for the source iqueryable doesn't implement
>   idbasyncqueryprovider

My controller method is:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetServiceId(string name)
{

    var service_id = await db.Services
                    .Where(s => (s.Service_Name == name))
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (service_id == null)
    {
         return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(service_id);
}
```

And the TestContext file is:

```
class TestContext : IContext
{
    public TestContext ()
    {
        this.Services = new TestServiceDbSet();
    }

    public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

And I've followed all the steps to the letter in that link above. I think TestDbSet code (see that link) has to be updated to account for async methods but I'm not sure how.

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Its your implementation of type `TestServiceDbSet`. There are 2 possible ways to do it and the first way will not work with `async` code, only the 2nd one will. Unfortunately the example you linked to does not mention this. See [Testing with your own test doubles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314431.aspx). I wrote a couple of extensions around this to make it easier to reuse throughout a test project, see [DbContext Data Mocking for Unit Testing](https://github.com/IgorWolbers/DbContextMockForUnitTests)

Comment: @Igor Thanks! Will take a look. Is there an easier way to test this using moq/nunit?

Comment: The testing harness does not matter too much. As far as creating fakes I prefer NSubstitute (available via NuGet) but I do not think that matters too much either, its more personal preference. Your design though has the biggest impact on the ability to test. Keeping your type references inside your controller as abstract/general as possible is the best way to ensure that testing is easy. When using EF I use reference type DbContext and never the derived types and use the Set<T>() to get the DbSets<T>, then its easy to inject a fake DbContext with mocked Set<T> in the Controller or Service.

Comment: [A quick reference](https://github.com/IgorWolbers/DbContextMockForUnitTests/blob/master/DbSetTests.cs) to the unit tests I created for the wrapper. This illustrates how to fake a DbContext, this could then be injected into your Controller using the controller's constructor and your Action would be `db.Set<Service>().Where(x => ..... /*rest of code*/).FirstOrAsync()`. You could also assign the DbSet directly to your TestContext as well, either way works as long as you are using interfaces or abstract types testing with fakes should be fairly easy to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to Implement an aync QueryProvider. Take a look at Testing with async queries in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx) article.